# Cannot reopen a connection of file when appending new data into it

Tags: r

I am trying to keep a log:

```
logcon <- file("log.txt", open="w+")

for(i in 1:10){
  writeLines(text=as.character(Sys.time()), con=logcon, sep="\n")
  Sys.sleep(3)
}

close(logcon)

open(logcon)
```

Questions

1. Every time when I create a connection, it creates a new file which overwrite the old one. How can I append new time log into the same file?
2. Before I close the connection, the log.txt shows nothing. All the logs show up after the connection is closed
3. When appending new data, `open(logcon)` returns `error > open(logcon)
   Error in open.connection(logcon) : invalid connection`

I tried

```
 for(i in 1:10){
   write.table(as.character(Sys.time()),"log.txt", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
   Sys.sleep(3)
}
```

Everything works well.

Comment: In `file`, you have an `open` mode for "appending in text mode", i.e. `a` or `at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as appending data goes, you need to use a different mode when you open the connection:

```
logcon<-file("log.txt", open="a")
```

As for the lines, you could always just try sink to redirect output instead of writeLines, e.g.

```
sink(logcon) # direct to your file connection
as.character(Sys.time()) # or whatever you want to push out. remember cat here
sink() # change your output back to terminal
```

Comment: If I try this:
`> logcon <- file("log42.txt", open="w+")
> close(logcon)
> open(logcon)
Error in open.connection(logcon) : invalid connection`
a new file named log42.txt will be created. Can I create a connection to a existing file but not a new one? How can I open a connection which had been closed?

Comment: you just told R you didn't want the connection, that it is now "unused". Try this: `> logcon <- file("log42.txt", open="w+") >logcon > close(logcon) >logcon` and you should see `Error in summary.connection(x) : invalid connection` for the second call to logcon. It's gone as far as R is concerned.